# OnException in Camel not returning a custom response

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am having this issue in my apache camel code which I am trying to resolve from last two days, but I could not resolve it.

I have two routes. First route is as below:

```
public class XXXRoute1 extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() {
        String endpointUri = "cxf:/XXX;
        String logEndpoint = "log:" + XXX() + "?level=DEBUG";
        from(endpointUri)
                .to(logEndpoint).to(ROUTE2.ENDPOINT_URI)
                .to(logEndpoint);
    }
```

Second Route:(In second route , I am catching some exception through onException)

```
public class Route2 extends RouteBuilder {
 public void configure() throws  Exception{
        String integrationEndpoint = "xxx.integration";
onException(RuntimeException.class).handled(true).onWhen(exceptionMessage().contains("Invalid")).bean(translator, "translateSomeError(${property.XXX})").end();

from(ENDPOINT_URI)
.
.
. so on
```

Now , In my case, the object which I am populating through onException

```
public SomeObjectResponse translateSomeError(Object someObject) throws  Exception{


        SomeObjectResponse someObjectResponse = new SomeObjectResponse();
someObjectResponse.setError("someError");

        return someObjectResponse ;
}
```

However, In SOAP UI while testing I am getting an empty SOAP envelop

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using cxf component in apache camel.

Comment: What do you expect CXF to return? A SOAP `Fault`? Or your `SomeObjectResponse` instance marshalled inside the body?

Comment: Hi @Ralf , I want to return someobjectResponse .

Comment: And `SomeObjectResponse` can be marshaled with JAXB? Are you generating your interface model classes from a schema?

Comment: I would guess there is some problem marshaling SomeObjectResponse. Have you tried to return an instance of a class that is confirmed to marshal correctly during normal operation?

Comment: @Ralf, well this object is properly marshalled back in cases where the exception is not thrown. But, when exception is thrown and cathced, the response is well populated, but looks like the camel exchange is left with something, which is not returning the expected response.

Comment: Does it work if you replace the `onException` handler with a `try-catch`?

Comment: No, As soon as the exception is thrown, Even if it is handled through try catch block in java, It still gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your route completely ? Where you have the onException ?

Also before you use your custom class, can you try this ? Just want to make sure anything set at onException is propagated back to CXF endpoint:

onException(RuntimeException.class).handled(true).setBody().simple("</Unexpected exception> ");

Comment: Hi Gnanagurus, I have tried setBody but it too gave a blank response. Also, I am using Onexception as the first line inside the configure method of routebuilder.

Comment: 2 things I would suggest : 1. Use doTry 2. This sounds silly, but try removing all log endpoints in your route and try.

Answer (score 0):

The onException() block appears to be in your second route and is consequently not in scope of your first route.

Make the onException() block global or add it to your CXF route so it's in scope.

Comment: Hi Ninja,      I have already tried to make the scope global by extending both of the routes making a common parent class, MyRouteBuilder but it didnt help either.  If there is any other way to make the scope global?

Comment: A common parent class will not make exception block global, just create two instances of it (one for each subclass route).  Try defining your onException() block AND routes in a single RouteBuilder, to get something that works.  Defining everything in XML makes it simpler to make onException() global...